# SSH Connection Issue in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssh, spring-jdbc, jsch

I have a remote database currently hosted on namecheap via [premium208.web-hosting.com](https://premium208.web-hosting.com) using the cpanel which only allows SSH connections to the database that i want to use in my spring boot application. So far I have the following Error with my current configuration:

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:683)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:230)
    at io.rddghs.config.ExternalDBAccess.establishDatabaseConnection(ExternalDBAccess.java:21)
    at io.rddghs.services.PostService.getAllPosts(PostService.java:33)
    at io.rddghs.controllers.PostsController.indexView(PostsController.java:60)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1070)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:484)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:581)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readServerCapabilities(NativeProtocol.java:536)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.beforeHandshake(NativeProtocol.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1431)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:133)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:948)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:818)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.FullReadInputStream.readFully(FullReadInputStream.java:67)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeaderLocal(SimplePacketReader.java:81)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:45)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:575)
    ... 62 more
Hibernate: select post0_.id as id1_0_, post0_.content as content2_0_, post0_.created_at as created_3_0_, post0_.photos as photos4_0_, post0_.title as title5_0_, post0_.user_id as user_id6_0_ from posts post0_ order by post0_.created_at desc
```

In my application.properties i have it configured like this:

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=America/Chicago
spring.datasource.username=myUserName
spring.datasource.password=myPassword

#SSH Connections
spring.ssh.host=premium208.web-hosting.com:21098
spring.ssh.port=22
spring.ssh.username=myUserName
spring.ssh.password=myPassword

spring.queries.users-query=select user_name, password_hash, id from users where user_name=?
spring.queries.roles-query=select user_name, 'ADMIN' AS 'role' from users where user_name=?

# 
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

In my config, i have this class which uses the JSch library:

```
public class ExternalDBAccess {
    public void establishDatabaseConnection() {
        try {
            JSch jSch = new JSch();
            Session session = jSch.getSession("myusername", "premium208.web-hosting.com", 21098);
            session.setPassword("mypassword");
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.connect();
            int localPort = session.setPortForwardingL(0, "premium208.web-hosting.com:21098", 3306);

            // Create the database connection using the local port
            String databaseUrl = String.format("jdbc:mysql://localhost:%d/mydb?characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=America/Chicago", localPort);
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseUrl, "myusername", "mypassword");

            // Use the connection for database operations

            // Close the database connection and SSH session when finished
            connection.close();
            session.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In my post controller class, this is how i am accessing them:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String indexView(Model model) {
    List<Post> posts = postService.getAllPosts(); // Fetch the posts using PostService
    model.addAttribute("posts", posts);
    model.addAttribute("posts5", posts.stream().limit(3).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    return "index";
}
```

In my post service class i have this method:

```
public List<Post> getAllPosts() {
        externalDBAccess.establishDatabaseConnection(); //SSH Tunnel
        return postRepository.findAllByOrderByCreatedAtDesc();
        }
```

Also in the view, i have this:

```
 <div class="col-7">
                        <div class="title-box">
                            <h5 class="heading-primary mt-4">
                                <u>Current News</u>
                            </h5>
                        </div>
                        <!--Section: Post data-mdb-->
                        <article th:each="p : ${posts}">
                            <h6 class="title" th:text="${p.title}">Post Title</h6>
                            <div class="date">
                                <i>Posted on</i> <span
                                    th:text="${#dates.format(p.createdAt, 'dd-MMM-yyyy')}">22-May-2022</span>
                                <!-- <span th:if="${p.author}" th:remove="tag"> <i>by</i> <span
                                    th:text="${p.author.fullName != null ? p.author.fullName : p.author.userName}">Admin</span>
                                </span>-->
                            </div>
                            <p class="content" th:utext="${p.content}"
                               style="text-align: justify">Post content</p>
                        </article>
                        <br>
                    </div>
```

I don't know what i'm doing it but the view is not fetching the data from the remote database. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You make an SSH connection, setup tunneling and then close the session again... So how should forwarding after that work? Also you shouldn't be calling this manually but rather in a bean that (eagerly) creates the session and does a setup for the forwarding.